# How I can I do TDD with Caller Info attributes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

In C# 5, they introduced the [Caller Info attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx). One of the useful applications is, quite obviously, logging. In fact, their example given is exactly that:

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

I am currently developing an application and I am at the point where I would like to introduce the usage of the caller info in my logging routines. Assume that I had the relatively simple logging interface of:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Info(String message);
}
```

Normally, I'd use Moq to verify the behavior I desire:

```
// Arrange
var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
var sut = new SystemUnderTest(logger.Object);

// Act
sut.DoIt();

// Assert
logger.Verify(log => log.Info("DoIt was called"));
```

That's all fine. Now I'd like to modify my logging interface such that it accepts caller info parameters:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Info(String message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
                              [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
                              [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);
}
```

For brevity, you can assume the implementation is similar to the `TraceMessage` example above. I can't simply create and verify my mock as above. The compiler error I receive is:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

The only way around this is to use the `It.IsAny<T>` matcher in Moq:

```
// Arrange
var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
var sut = new SystemUnderTest(logger.Object);

// Act
sut.DoIt();

// Assert
logger.Verify(log => log.Info("DoIt was called",
              It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
```

Unfortunately, I can't assert or verify that the call site looks the way I expect it to:

```
public void DoIt()
{
    // do hard work
    _logger.Info("DoIt was called");
}
```

Which brings me to my question: **How can I verify the behavior of Caller Info attributes in a unit test?**

I don't particularly like the `It.IsAny<T>` hack. I can write the unit test, run through a red-green cycle and all is well *until someone tries to modify it*. Then, someone can come along and modify my implementation to contain erroneous parameters and the test will still pass.

---

## Solution

Based on Herr Kater's answer, I was able to wrap the caller information into a utility class with the following method:

```
public CallerInfo GetCallerInformation()
{
    var frame = new StackFrame(2, true);

    return new CallerInfo
    {
        FileName = frame.GetFileName(),
        MethodName = frame.GetMethod().Name,
        LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber()
    };
}
```

I could then inject this dependency into my code and verify that the logger implementation was properly using it. My callers can now be properly tested if they are using the logging correctly.

```
// Arrange
var backingLog = new IMock<IBackingLog>();

var callerInfoUtility = new Mock<ICallerInfoUtility>();

var info = new CallerInfo { MethodName = "Test", FileName = "File", LineNumber = 123 };
callerInfoUtility.Setup(utility => utility.GetCallerInformation()).Returns(info);

var logger = new Logger(backingLog.Object, callerInfoUtility.Object);

// Act
logger.Log("test");

// Assert
logger.Verify(log => log.Info("test was called: Line 123 of Test in File"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some information from the StackFrame object.

```
 var stackFrame = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1, true);
 var fileName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
 var lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
 var callerMethod = stackFrame.GetMethod();
```

Comment: So essentially I can pull out the behavior of the caller info into something that is non-dependent on the optional parameter behavior.

Comment: I think so, but creating a stackframe is very expensive.

Comment: Is it more expensive relative to the Caller Info attributes? In practice, the logging would be used for exceptions and fatal errors, not for general info.

Comment: The caller info attributes are comiler features.You don't have to verify them. There is an other alternative. You can work with the StackTrace property of the exception. It provides all the necessary information. You can parse it with regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not verifying how or if they work, but rather if the *caller* is using them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `It.IsAny<string>()` you could use `It.Is<string>(callerMemberName => callerMemberName == "ExpectedCallerMemberName")` to verify the the functionality of this parameter, like this:

```
logger.Verify(log => log.Info("DoIt was called",
    It.Is<string>(callerMemberName => callerMemberName == "ExpectedCallerMemberName"), ..., ...));
```